# Setting Up X-Debug - PHP

Tags: php, xdebug

I want to use X-Debug in my PHP project to profile it !
So i downloaded the extension added to php.ini and wrote this line too

xdebug.profiler_enable=1
xdebug.profiler_append=1
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.trace_options=1

In phpinfo() i can see X-Debug extension, now how to start ?
Plz help !

`This worked, but how to read it :( !`
;X-Debug config
xdebug.profiler_enable=1
xdebug.profiler_append=1
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.trace_options=1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir ="E:/wamp/tmp"
xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%s.%H"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need an IDE that also supports xdebug.  Many editors support it, others may need plugins installed.  What editor are you using?  Notepad++, Eclipse (and variants), and even VIM support xdebug.

Comment: I found this article on Google [Setting up XDebug with Notepadd++](http://amiworks.co.in/talk/debugging-php-using-xdebug-and-notepad-part-i/)  Also if you're using firefox there are a few plugins that allow you to easily toggle xdebug on and off.